# Implement one javascript code and load dynamically more scripts

Tags: javascript

i would like to give our client one javascript code (e.g. Google Tag Manager) he/she has to implement on the website.

When this script is called i want to have a config file per client which features this client has enabled. Lets say we have 3 features:

feature1.js
feature2.js
feature3.js

Every feature is doing something else on the website (e.g. tracking user data, displaying a widget, etc.)

**My questions:**
1. How would you store the config which features are enabled? This should be flexible, whenever we add feature4.js, we just can enable it and the script will be loaded and the client does not have to implement new js code
2. Regarding performance, how would you do it? We are using AWS CloudFront.

Basically this is kind of the Google Tag Manager concept: One Code and on backend side the client can decide which JS code to be loaded / injected.

Thank you very much for your ideas!

Comment: Why not just use Google Tag Manager?

Comment: you want to do something then load a script then do something then loading a script is that it ?

Comment: Yes i want to load a script ... this script will read a config which will tell what other scripts to load ... and afterwards load those scripts

Comment: @ceejayoz if i would use it only for my site, yes ... but we want to provide this solution to our clients, so we cannot use it

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is just to inject the required lib into the DOM.

On this example, the script will be the second element on the page.

You may want sometimes to inject at the bottom of the DOM.

```js
function userlib1(){
  let lib = document.getElementsByTagName('*')[1],
      inj = document.createElement('script')
      inj.src = 'https://..../script.js'
  lib.appendChild(inj)
}
```

To store user data's, we can use `localstorage`, just like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('userdata','lib4')
console.log( localStorage.getItem('userdata') )
```

Comment: So you mean the customer should inject the basic javascript file and inside this javascript file we should run through the config (we maybe get from a json file) and then appendChild(inj) each of the scripts?

Comment: So maybe the customer will do something like that:  

<script src="https://domainl.tld/script.js?customer=123"></script>

Inside the script.js we can fetch the needed enabled scripts for customer 123, and then inject those scripts and maybe javascript code.

Comment: Passing a variable would be a way to do it server side. The way I shown is full client side, the browser will retrieve the needed libs only if needed. 
You can pass variable by the url into the script too, but it is over complicated, from my view.

Comment: Right, but then our client has to change the code whenever a new lib need to be injected. My aim is to have a solution like Google Tag Manager. Implement once and the rest can be handled via backend setup.

Comment: I made an update regarding a way to store user data client side. This data stay on when the user close his browser, and is much faster than cookies.

Comment: Good idea, but this would not really be helpful. Because when we cache the needed libs in users localStorage and the client enables more libs, we also need to invalidate the localStorage which is not possible. So i guess the only solution is to load the needed libs server side, which also can be cached .. but on our side and we can invalidate the cache whenever the customer changed the settings.

Comment: Sure, you got to make all the mechanical yourself. I always don't want to overkill too much, but it can be wrong.! This said, we can set many localstorage key entries, containing many differents things. It can be the full lib (encode to base64 to store) or just the declaration of the needed lib. The browser will make all the caching anyway, as soon as one lib is retrieved. Browser are smart nowadays ;)